# Grouping some result sql fields into a common object

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to understand if it is possible using the sqlalchemy core syntax to get the given data in the same format as with pure SQL.

DB relations

```
events = Table(
    "events",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
        ......
        
    Column("location_id", ForeignKey(locations.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("activities_id", ForeignKey(activities.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),

)

locations = Table(
    "locations",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    ....
    ....
)

activities = Table(
    "activities",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    ....
)
```

I want to group the fields from the tables locations and activities into a separate group. In plain SQL this query runs like this (using Postgresql)

```
SELECT json_build_object('id', e.id, 'title', e.title, 'creator', json_agg(c), " \
        'activitie', json_agg(a), 'users', jsonb_agg(u), 'location', jsonb_agg(l)) " \
        AS event FROM events AS e " \
        LEFT JOIN event_users AS eu ON e.id = eu.events_id " \
        LEFT JOIN users AS u ON eu.users_id = u.id " \
        LEFT JOIN users AS c ON e.creator = c.id " \
        LEFT JOIN activities AS a ON e.activities_id = a.id " \
        LEFT JOIN locations AS l ON e.location_id = l.id " \
        WHERE e.id = {_id} GROUP BY e.id
```

And the result is

```
{'event': 
    '{
    "id" : 1, "title" : "Test",  
    "creator" : [{"id":1,"created_at":"2021-03-03T23:39:23.469751+03:00","email":"test@email","phone":"232323","hashed_password":"sdsdsds","is_active":true}], 
    "activitie" : [{"id":1,"name":"basketball","is_active":true}], 
    "users" : [null], 
    "location" : [{"id": 3, "lat": 54.49142965, "city": "Berlin", "long": 26.9173560217231, "street": "Stephans", "building": "12"}]
    }'
}
```

As you can see each Foreignkey field is grouped under a common key.
Now I'm trying to do something similar on the sqlalchemy core (without the user table)

```
query = (
    select(
        [
         events.c.id,
         events.c.title,
         locations.c.city,
         locations.c.street,
         locations.c.building,
         activities.c.name,
        ]
    )
    .select_from(
        events.join(locations).join(activities)
    )
    .where(
        and_(
            events.c.id == pk,
            locations.c.id == events.c.location_id,
            activities.c.id == events.c.activities_id)
    )
    .order_by(desc(events.c.created_at))
 )
print(query)
ev = dict(await database.fetch_one(query))
```

And get the result

```
{'id': 1, 'title': 'Test', 'city':Berlin', street': 'Stephans', 'building': '12', 'name': 'basketball'}
```

How to group result like ?

```
{
'id': 1, 
'title': 'Test',
'location': [ 
        'city': 'Berlin'
        'street': 'Stephans', 
        'building': '12',
        ],
'activity': [ 
        'name': 'basketball'
    

]
```

}

**p.s. sql query with @van's code**

```
SELECT json_build_object(:json_build_object_2, events.id, :json_build_object_3, events.title, :json_build_object_4, json_agg(json_build_object(:json_build_object_5, locations.city, :json_build_object_6, locations.street, :json_build_object_7, locations.building)), :json_build_object_8, json_agg(json_build_object(:json_build_object_9, locations.id, :json_build_object_10, locations.lat, :json_build_object_11, locations.long, :json_build_object_12, locations.city, :json_build_object_13, locations.street, :json_build_object_14, locations.building)), :json_build_object_15, json_agg(json_build_object(:json_build_object_16, activities.name))) AS json_build_object_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query should do the job:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
# ...

query = (
    select(
        [
            func.json_build_object(
                "id",
                events.c.id,
                "title",
                events.c.title,
                "location",
                func.json_agg(
                    func.json_build_object(
                        "city",
                        locations.c.city,
                        "street",
                        locations.c.street,
                        "building",
                        locations.c.building,
                    )
                ),
                "location_all_columns_example",
                func.json_agg(func.json_build_object(
                    *itertools.chain(*[(_.name, _) for _ in locations.c])
                )),
                "activity",
                func.json_agg(
                    func.json_build_object(
                        "name",
                        activities.c.name,
                    )
                ),
            )
        ]
    )
    .select_from(events.join(locations).join(activities))
    .where(
        and_(
            events.c.id == pk,
            locations.c.id == events.c.location_id,
            activities.c.id == events.c.activities_id,
        )
    )
    .order_by(desc(events.c.created_at))
    .group_by(events.c.id)  # !!! <- IMPORTANT
)
```

Please note that you need the `group_by` clause.

Comment: Hi, van! Thank for your response, now  I'm get the error `could not determine data type of parameter $2 ` . I added sql query format at the end of my question / Could you help with that ?

Comment: Might be depending on the version of the postgresql you have. I tested the code with 13. Try to split and use just for one field/column and progress from there.

Comment: Hmm, so strange. `PostgreSQL 13.2 (Ubuntu 13.2-1.pgdg18.04+1)`  I finde the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655943/sqlalchmey-func-json-build-object-throwing-error-could-not-determine-data-type

Comment: OK, maybe another hint: i have tested query execution only using `ev = session.execute(query).fetchone()`, while you and the linked example are using `async`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I'll look into it, thanks for your help.