# Subquery as column with SqlAlchemy expression language

Tags: sqlalchemy

Note that I'm not using an ORM but rather the expression [language](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html)

I'm trying to do a query which returns a Postgres json_agg as a column.
The SQL query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
   table1.id,
   table1.name,
   (
    SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
       "name",
       table2.name
    ))
   ) AS foobar
WHERE 
  table1.id = 1;
```

when I tried to do the following it turns the query into two FROM where the first is the subquery.

```py
select(
  [
   table1, 
   select([
     func.json_agg(
       func.json_build_object(
        text("name"), 
        table2.c.name)
       )
     )
    ])
  ])
  .where(table1.c.id == 1)
```

(the above might be syntactically wrong as I wrote it in stackoverflow just now to illustrate my point)

How to turn it into a `(select ...) as column_name` subquery?

Comment: Please see if this very recent Q/A helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718479/99594. _One difference might be that you seem to be referring to sqlalchemy 1.3 whereas the reference answer uses 1.4 syntax._

Comment: Unfortunatly not. That was how I started it but the json_aggs needs to be subqueries as columns before the WHERE because table2 can't be joined

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what you ask for with the query like below:

```
query = (
    select(
        table1,
        select(
            func.json_agg(
                func.json_build_object("name", table2.c.name)
            ).label("foobar")
        ).scalar_subquery(),  # <- THIS IS the key
    )
    .where(table1.c.id == 1)
)
```

*Please note that sqlalchemy 1.4 feature is used here; you might need to use `as_scalar()` instead of `scalar_subquery` in 1.3 and before.*

---

It might be just a incomplete example, but i think your query is not really complete as you will get the cartesian product of `table2` as a result. The solution might be (and i am guessing here) to simply use the `group_by` to allow using the functions without having them as sub-select like below:

```
query = (
    select([
        table1,
        func.json_agg(
            func.json_build_object("name", table2.c.name)  # NOTE: `text("name")` will fail in this example (ambigous between table2.name and table1.name, you simply want a string i assume
        ).label("foobar")
    ])
    .where(table1.c.id == 1)
    .join(table2)  # NOTE: i guess you want to join here, else you will get all entries from table2 in the "foobar"
    .group_by(table1)  # !!! <- IMPORTANT to allow the agg function to work
)
```

which should produce SQL similar to below:

```
SELECT table1.id,
       table1.name,
       json_agg(json_build_object('name', table2.name)) AS foobar
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
WHERE table1.id = 1
GROUP BY table1.id,
         table1.name
```